# Django test set created_at field

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have following model in Django (`models.py`)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Session(models.Model):
  session_token = models.TextField(default="")
  code = models.CharField(max_length= 5, default="")
  active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now, I have following function to be tested.

```
def get_active_session_older_than_hours(older_than_hours):
  older_date_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=older_than_hours)
  data = Session.objects\
    .filter(active=True, updated_at__lte=older_date_time)\
    .values_list('code')
  return data
```

I want to test it.

```
from django.test import TestCase


#Working fine
class ActiveSessionsNotPreset(TestCase):
  def test(self):
    data = get_active_session_older_than_hours(3)
    self.assertEqual(len(data), 0)


#This is not working.
#It is not getting the result.
class ActiveSessionPresent(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    older_date_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
    Session.objects.create(session_token='',
                                     code='US', active=True,
                                     created_at=older_date_time,
                                     updated_at=older_date_time)
  def test(self):
    data = get_active_session_older_than_hours(3)
    print("DEVENDER data " + str(data))
    self.assertEqual(len(data), 1)
```

In the second test case, I am not getting any result. What is the correct way to force `created_at` and `updated_at`?

Comment: check [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) library which allows you to mock date and time in tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use .update() as it would do UPDATE SQL statement that will not call any of Django methods

```
session = Session.objects.create(session_token='', ...).
session.filter(pk=session.pk).update(updated_at=older_date_time,..)
```

Other ideas are fixtures or mocking